# Count distinct array entries [with no add memory nor array changes]

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Task is count unique numbers of a given array. I saw numerous similar questions on SO, but here we have additional requirements, which weren't stated in other questions:

- Amount of allowed additional memory is O(1)
- Changes to array are
  prohibited

I was able to write quadratic algorithm, which agrees with given constraints. But I keep wondering, may one could do better on such a problem? Thank you for your time.
**Algorithm working with O(n^2)**

```
def count(a):
    unique = len(a)
    ind = 0
    while ind < len(a):
        x = a[ind]
        i = ind+1
        while i < len(a):
            if a[i] == x:
                unique -= 1
                break
            i += 1
        ind += 1

    print("Total uniques: ", unique)
```

Comment: Maybe more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @Barmar Disagree. I'm interested in no suggestions regarding my code. I'm in need of new ideas related to algorithm. Also, I can't help myself noticing that it happens rather a lot on SO, when users redirect askers somewhere else. I never see this behaviour on other hubs of stackexchange. SO supposed to preserve knowledge, right? Yes, question is a bit academical, but I posted in under algorithm subsection. So I think it's on proper place. So, let's finally get to the problem?:)

Comment: Do you have an upper bound for the array size? Is it sorted?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves I would write such details if they were given. But none of them are granted in this problem. No bound and unsorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very similar problem to a follow-up question in chapter 1 (Arrays and Strings) from *Cracking the Coding Interview*:

> Implement an algorithm to determine if a string has all unique
>   characters. What if you cannot use additional data structures?

The answer (to the follow-up question) is that if you can't assume anything about the array (namely, it is not sorted, you don't know its size, etc.), then there is no algorithm better than what you showed.

That being said, you may think about relaxing the constraints a little bit, to make it more interesting. For example, if you have an upper bound on the array size, you could use a bit vector to keep track of which values you've read before while traversing the array, although this is not strictly an `O(1)` solution when it comes to memory usage (one could argue that by knowing the maximum array size, the memory usage is constant, and thus `O(1)`, but that is a little bit of cheating). Similarly, if the array was sorted, you could also solve it in `O(n)` by going through each element at a time and check if its neighbors are different numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no underlying structure in the array given (sorted, etc.) you are forced to brute force every value in the array...

There is a more complicated approach that I believe would work. It entails keeping your array of unique numbers sorted. This means that it would take more time when inserting into the array but would allow you to look-up values much quicker. You should be able to insert into the array in logn time by looking at the value directly in the middle of the array and checking if it's larger or smaller. You'd then eliminate half the array as a valid insertion location and repeat. You would use a similar approach to look-up values in the array. The only issue with this is that it requires more memory space than I believe you are allocated (1).

That being said, I think given the constraints on the task restrict the algorithm to O(n^2).

Comment: How exactly do you pretend to insert elements into a sorted array in `log(n)` time? Sure, you can *find* where to put it in `O(log(n))` time, but inserting elements anywhere in an array other than at the end requires you to shift every elements after that position to the right. This kind of blows the `log(n)` time.

Comment: This is true. I overlooked that.